# Create a dataframe from some rows of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is the DataFrame I am working with, for reference.

```
data2 = {'col10':[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0], 'col11':[100, 200, 300, 400]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data2, index = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

I'm trying to create a new DataFrame, df2, from the last two rows of this column. I'm not sure how to do this and would appreciate some tips.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
newdf=df.loc[['c','d']]

>>> print(newdf)
   col10  col11
c    3.0    300
d    4.0    400
```

If you want a more generic solution, for example if you don;t know the index of your last tow rows, you can use the following:

```
newdf=df.iloc[-2:]

>>> print(newdf)
   col10  col11
c    3.0    300
d    4.0    400
```